# Calling virtual method on subclass returns superclass data

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have two classes and want to get meta information of the subclass:

```
class DataObject : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
    public:
         virtual void meta() {
             const QMetaObject *mo = QObject::metaObject();

             for (int i = 0; i < mo->propertyCount(); i++) {
                 qDebug() << mo->property(i).name() << mo->property(i).read(this);
             }
         }
    ...
}

class User : public DataObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int id MEMBER m_id)
    ...
}
```

When I call meta on a `User` Object it only outputs the default object property `objectName`, not the properties declared in the User class.

Can I get the meta information of the subclasses somehow without implementing the method in every single one by hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to invoke `metaObject()` via dynamic dispatch, not statically (`Class::method()` is static dispatch). You also don't need `meta()` to be virtual, nor even a method - it should be a free standing function, it applies to any object you pass to it; C++ is not Java.

An example follows. Output:

```
objectName QVariant(QString, "")
id QVariant(int, 1)
```

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/meta-derived-38268004
#include <QtCore>

void meta(QObject * obj) {
   auto mo = obj->metaObject();
   for (int i = 0; i < mo->propertyCount(); i++)
      qDebug() << mo->property(i).name() << mo->property(i).read(obj);
}

struct DataObject : QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
};

struct User : DataObject {
   Q_PROPERTY(int id MEMBER m_id)
   Q_OBJECT
   int m_id { 1 };
};

int main() {
   User user;
   Q_ASSERT(user.metaObject()->propertyCount() == 2);
   meta(&user);
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly calling `QObject::metaObject()` method, i.e. method of `QObject` base class. Remove `QObject::` part from your `meta()` implementation and so that virtual implementation of `metaObject()` will be called at runtime